# IBM MQ PCF parameters order

Tags: ibm-mq

Does anybody know why when I try to inquire channel with MQCMD_INQUIRE_CHANNEL command with these parameters in this order I have error MQRCCF_MSG_LENGTH_ERROR:

```
ChannelName (MQCFST)
ChannelAttrs (MQCFIL) can have any single or multiple attributes except MQIACF_ALL. With MQIACF_ALL works OK.
IntegerFilterCommand (MQCFIF)
```

If I change order (put MQCFIL structure to the end) it works OK:

```
ChannelName (MQCFST)
IntegerFilterCommand (MQCFIF)
ChannelAttrs (MQCFIL)
```

Similar inquire for queue (MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q) works OK in both cases with any QAttrs values:

```
QName (MQCFST)
QAttrs (MQCFIL)
IntegerFilterCommand (MQCFIF)
```

and

```
QName (MQCFST)
IntegerFilterCommand (MQCFIF)
QAttrs (MQCFIL)
```

Debug info:

[runmqras](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ym0rzo2oxcbnfs/runmqras-44d7e2862427.zip?dl=0)

[message](https://www.dropbox.com/s/siqm58m7ey6cm1n/message?dl=0)

[part of the code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mjd0b44ospwogme/code_snippet.py?dl=0)

The one of the strangest thing for me is MQIACF_ALL parameter, simple replacement it with any other allowable parameter (ex MQCACH_DESC) brokes inquire.

PS
I use python (pymqi branch without MQAI) for creating MQ PCF message.
If it is really needed I can create sample C program for approve, but I checked resulting binary message multiple times and it has no issue.

Comment: "anyone know why?" - defective code in MQ command server?

Comment: Maybe someone already saw this issue

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suspect this is a bug in MQ.  Can you take a trace of the command server on the queue manager while running your program?  The command server process is named amqpcsea, or amqpcsea.exe on Windows.  In these commands replace QMGRNAME with your actual queue manager name and TSxxxxxxxxx with your IBM case number once you've opened it:

```
strmqtrc -m QMGRNAME -p amqpcsea[.exe]
/* Run the program to get the error */
endmqtrc -a
runmqras -qmlist QMGRNAME -section defs,trace -caseno TSxxxxxxxxx
```

Upload the zip file from runmqras along with the binary command message (since it appears you can capture it), and we can review it.

Could you also clarify your point about MQIACF_ALL?  When you say that replacing it with any other parameter breaks inquire, what kind of error are you getting in that case?  It sounds as if there might be two errors, and I want to make sure I understand them both properly.

As for parameter order, the only restriction I know is that distributed (non-z/OS) platforms need the required parameters first: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q086880_.htm

Comment: Hi @justinf,
runmqras result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ym0rzo2oxcbnfs/runmqras-44d7e2862427.zip?dl=0
message body: https://www.dropbox.com/s/siqm58m7ey6cm1n/message?dl=0
part of the code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mjd0b44ospwogme/code_snippet.py?dl=0

Comment: Error is MQRCCF_MSG_LENGTH_ERROR
I added Debug Info to initial post.
Thank you!

Comment: @Seyf do you have ability to open a case with IBM?

Comment: My customers does not use python for MQ. If it's really needed, I will ask tomorrow.